# org-mode timestamp repeater interval manipulation

Tags: org-mode, time-date, parse-time

What are (if any) the lisp functions to read and write the repeater interval part of the `org-mode` timestamps? (The ones at the end of the timestamp string, which are optional, e.g. `+1w` or `+6d` in `<2016-03-03 Thu .+6d -3d>` or `[2016-01-27 Wed ++1w -2d]`)

If there are none such functions, how does one approach creating them?

Any way to convert them to seconds for use in arithmetic manipulations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `org-element-timestamp-parser` (parses the timestamp at point, including the repeater part) and `org-element-timestamp-interpreter` (transforms a timestamp object back into Org syntax).

For example, calling `(org-element-timestamp-parser)` with the point at the "`<`" of "`<2016-01-25 Mon 14:51 +1w>`" produces

```el
(timestamp (:type active
            :raw-value "<2016-01-25 Mon 14:51 +1w>"
            :year-start 2016
            :month-start 1
            :day-start 25
            :hour-start 14
            :minute-start 51
            :year-end 2016
            :month-end 1
            :day-end 25
            :hour-end 14
            :minute-end 51
            :begin 1
            :end 27
            :post-blank 0
            :repeater-type cumulate
            :repeater-value 1
            :repeater-unit week))
```

The second element of this list is a [property list](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Property-Lists.html#Property-Lists) that can be easily accessed and changed using `plist-get` and `plist-put`.

PS: I found these by running `zrgrep` in the Org source directory, searching for "repeater".

PPS: I use Org-mode version 8.2.10.

Comment: Wow! I didn't realize this is so an advanced topic, that my Org-mode version 7.8 doesn't include this function. Gotta go upgrade emacsen on all of my computers now, and still a lot of programming lays ahead of me.